# Is it possible to create an ImageParam with a predefined size for a Halide pipeline?

Tags: halide

Currently, I am trying to cross compile a Halide pipeline. The arguments for the pipeline were initially

```
ImageParam ifm(type_of<float>(), 4, "ifm");
ImageParam kernel(type_of<float>(), 4, "kernel");
ImageParam bias(type_of<float>(), 1, "bias");
Param<int> stride_x;
Param<int> stride_y;
Param<int> pad_x;
Param<int> pad_y;

vector<Argument> args(7);
args[0] = ifm;
args[1] = kernel;
args[2] = bias;
args[3] = pad_x;
args[4] = pad_y;
args[5] = stride_x;
args[6] = stride_y;
```

After successfully compiling and testing the function, it was found that the function call was taking a good amount of time for each run. I tried to minimize the number of arguments to speed up the call and it worked. Currently, the arguments being passed to the function is just the ifm.(I am trying to perform convolution)

```
ImageParam ifm(type_of<float>(), 4, "ifm");
vector<Argument> args(1);
args[0] = ifm;
```

It took a lot less time for each pipeline call. I figured that Halide might be JIT compiling the pipeline before running it and that is adding the overhead as less arguments results in less dimension resolves during run time.(Not sure, can somebody confirm?)

To fully statically compile the pipeline, I think that `ImageParam` could be constructed with a predefined size as I already know the size of the image being passed to the pipeline.I looked at the `ImageParam` class but found no constructor that would suit my needs. Is there any workaround?

P.S. Is there is any other way of cross compiling Halide pipelines? I have checked generators but I think it also has the same shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor that allows you to set the size of the input. However, once your ImageParam is constructed, you can use the ImageParam::dim() method to set the dimensions. For example, in your case, if the input sizes are stored in a vector named `dims` you could call

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  ifm.dim(i).set_bounds(0, dims[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but got no improvement in run_time. Maybe it is setting bounds but still during final resolution of the dimension value, still taking it during runtime and just keeping a check whether it is between the given bounds.